# ModelAndViewContainer is empty when ModelAndView has object and viewName

Tags: java, spring, rest, kotlin, thymeleaf

I am trying to return ModelAndView,
In debug mode I found ModelAndView has:
view = "recordstable"
model has 1 List,
but when it is returning ModelAndViewContainer view is null and default model is empty.

recordstable.html replaced in resources/templates

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/csv")
class AuthorRecordController(private val authorRecordService: AuthorRecordService) {
@GetMapping("/records", produces = arrayOf("application/json"))
@ResponseBody
fun getRecords() : ModelAndView
{
    val model = ModelAndView()
    val listOfRecords = authorRecordService.getAllRecords()
    model.addObject("listOfRecords", listOfRecords)
    model.viewName = "recordstable"
    return model
}
```

}

Comment: Remove `@ResponseBody` as that is for returning info to rest controllers (like JSON or XML) not for returning a view with a model to render.